# the enemy detect and follows one of the characters,but don't detect the other characters when chanced the played character using character select menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In the unity I'm making a RPG game. This game include enemies and more than one character that can selected in menu. But enemies are just detect and follow one of characters, when I change played character in-game menu the enemies doesn't detect the player everytime but detect sometimes with little bit chance.

**this is the part of my enemy script that detecting player,**

```
GameObject player;
    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator anim;
    float timePassed;
    float newDestinationCD = 0.5f;


    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

   void Update()
    {
        anim.SetFloat("speed", agent.velocity.magnitude / agent.speed);

        if (timePassed >= attackCD)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position) <= attackRange)
            {
                anim.SetTrigger("attack");
                timePassed = 0;
            }
        }
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

        if (newDestinationCD <= 0 && Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position) <= aggroRange)
        {
            newDestinationCD = 0.5f;
            agent.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
        }
        newDestinationCD -= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.LookAt(player.transform);
   }
```

**this is player selection script,**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PlayerSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] characterList;
    private int index;
    private void Start()
    {
        index = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selectedCharacter");

        characterList = new GameObject[transform.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
            characterList[i] = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        foreach (GameObject go in characterList)
            go.SetActive(false);
        if (characterList[index])
            characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }
    public void NextCharacter()
    {
        characterList[index].SetActive(false);

        index++;
        if (index == characterList.Length)
        {
            index =0;
        }

        characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void PreviousCharacter()
    {
        characterList[index].SetActive(false);

        index--;
        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = characterList.Length - 1;
        }

        characterList[index].SetActive(true);
    }

    public void startGame()
    {
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selectedCharacter", index);
      SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }

   

}
```

I tried now again and it detected on first start chonon(3rd), and later i changed character to maria(2nd) using in-game menu, it doesn't detect and later i selected ganfaul(1st) it detected but when i change one more time to chonon it doesn't detected, But ganfaul is always detected when i select it.

[image]

[video(sorry for lagging)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17qMfl-qatPK4mFXw41w3_KCK-D1NtOrn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It seems like you are initially only looking for one character gameobject in the start method. Can you be more clear on how many character objects you have and share some photos about the enemy set-up and scene set-up?

Comment: GameObject.FindWithTag("Player"); no matter what its on will always find the first.. its not a random list of.. if you want a random list of you need to find all and pick a random

Comment: I added a photo and video if you can write me from discord I'd appreciate Discord: scar_fia

Comment: okey I solved it using chat gpt

Comment: Thats great to hear! Maybe post the solution in the answers so others with the same problem can benefit from it!

Comment: I would assume your selection only changes the players visuals (skin) but it keeps being the same object anyway?